# Зачем в FileSplit нужен рандомный генератор?

Tags: java, datavec

Один из конструкторов [`FileSplit`](https://deeplearning4j.org/datavecdoc/org/datavec/api/split/FileSplit.html) (класс из [DataVec](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec)) имеет вид:

```
FileSplit(java.io.File rootDir, java.lang.String[] allowFormat, java.util.Random rng)
```

Зачем нужен аргумент `Random rng`?

Comment: О каком `FileSplit` идет речь? Укажите пакет, если класс не из JDK, то добавьте также ссылку на библиотеку.

Comment: вот отсюда:  org.datavec.api.split https://deeplearning4j.org/datavecdoc/org/datavec/api/split/FileSplit.html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Там в методе `initialize` и в `reset` [перемешивание происходит](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/blob/master/datavec-api/src/main/java/org/datavec/api/split/FileSplit.java#L107), если был передан `Random`:

```
protected void initialize() {
    [...]
    if (randomize) {
            iterationOrder = new int[subFiles.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < iterationOrder.length; i++) {
                iterationOrder[i] = i;
            }
            RandomUtils.shuffleInPlace(iterationOrder, random);
    }
    [...]
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    if (randomize) {
        //Shuffle the iteration order
        RandomUtils.shuffleInPlace(iterationOrder, random);
    }
}
```